# Trouble with gems installation in JRuby with RVM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, jruby

I'm using Linux Mint. I've already installed jruby and jdk.

When I check ruby version it gives me correct message

`ruby -v
jruby 1.7.11 (1.9.3p392) 2014-02-24 86339bb on Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.8.0_05-b13 +indy [linux-i386]`

But when I try to install some gems like this:

`gem install bundler`

It gives me this message:

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (SocketError)
    recv: name or service not known`

**which jruby**
`/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/bin/jruby`

**which gem**

`/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/bin/gem`

**gem env**

`RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 392) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/bin/jruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/msdc/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-java-1.8
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11
     - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11/bin
     - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11@global/bin
     - /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /home/msdc/bin
     - /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05/bin
     - /home/msdc/bin
     - /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/bin
     - /home/msdc/bin
     - /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05/bin
     - /home/msdc/bin
     - /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/bin
     - /home/msdc/.rvm/bin`

When I run `gem install bundler` in debug mode it gives me this:

```
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv.rb:775:in `recv_reply'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv.rb:663:in `request'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv.rb:511:in `each_resource'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv.rb:0:in `resolv'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv.rb:1026:in `resolv'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv.rb:1025:in `resolv'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv.rb:1023:in `resolv'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv.rb:503:in `each_resource'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv.rb:480:in `getresource'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:88:in `api_endpoint'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/source.rb:42:in `api_uri'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/source.rb:170:in `load_specs'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:265:in `tuples_for'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:226:in `available_specs'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each_source'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:222:in `available_specs'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:102:in `search_for_dependency'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:216:in `find_gems_with_sources'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:292:in `find_spec_by_name_and_version'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:166:in `available_set_for'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:418:in `resolve_dependencies'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:371:in `install'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:219:in `install_gem'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:263:in `install_gems'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:259:in `install_gems'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:171:in `execute'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/command_manager.rb:167:in `process_args'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/command_manager.rb:137:in `run'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/bin/jgem:21:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101:in `load'
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/bin/gem:4:in `(root)'
```

Exception `Gem::SystemExitException' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.11/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:381 - Exiting RubyGems with exit_code 1

Comment: there were some issues with +indy (Java 8) ... maybe, just to make sure it does not interfere, I would try installing Java 7 (than just change `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/7/home`)

Comment: I've tried to downgrade to Java 1.7.0_55 version, but it reports same error: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (SocketError)
    recv: name or service not known`

Comment: there's very likely something wrong about your DNS resolution (following the back-trace).

so I would try fixing that by following `Resolv`'s source and making sure code such as `Socket.gethostbyname("rubygems.org")` works (in irb) first.

Comment: Socket works in irb and it gives me this command: `["ec2-54-245-255-174.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", [], 2, "6\xF5\xFF\xAE"] `

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying http://rubygems.org and seeing if that works.  https should work, but at least then you'd know more precisely what the problem is.  You'll probably find this config information in your ~/.gemrc file.

Comment: It's weird, but I've solved my problem with switching to **jruby-1.7.13**. Installation of gems in jruby-1.7.12 doesn't work, but in jruby-1.7.13 it does.